# Keep displayField on Ext.form.Combobox in EditorGridPanel after selecting item?

Tags: extjs, combobox, gridpanel

I am using an Ext.form.Combobox on a column model editor, and this ColumnModel is put in to an EditorGridPanel. After I select an item in combobox, the text displayed on combobox is always  the valueField, not displayField. How can I keep the displayField on combobox in EditorGridPanel after selecting any item?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `renderer` method for the column to display the desired text.

```
renderer: function(val){
    // select the display text for val from the combobox's store
    return display text;
}
```